# I wanna get help about delays and loops in Python

Tags: python

When I put a delay before a loop that has delay inside a function, the function seem to not delay and loop when called.

```py
from time import *
from random import * 

def _print(s):
    global e_times
    print(s)
    return 10

def doloop(l_delay, s_delay):
    sleep(s_delay)
    while True:
        sleep(l_delay)

doloop(_print('Hello, world!'), 20)
```

My expectation that the output must delay for 20 seconds then and for each 10 seconds it must print the 'Hello, world!' string once. But when executed, it doesn't both delay and loop. What should I do?

Comment: If you are expecting it to print Hello, world! every 10 seconds, then it won't happen. It will print once and return 10. Which will be used to delay inside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
doloop(_print('Hello, world!'), 20)
```

This will do the following:

- evaluate `_print('Hello world!')` -> get 10
- call `doLoop` like this: `doLoop(10, 20)`

Functions arguments are evaluated first before being passed down to functions. 
So you will obviously not get a loop that calls the function multiple times.

What you need to do is pass the function itself to the `doLoop` method. And use it's return value.

```
def doloop(call_func, s_delay):
    sleep(s_delay)
    while True:
        l_delay = call_func()
        sleep(l_delay)
```

And then call it with:

```
doloop(lambda: _print('Hello, world!'), 20)
```

The lambda here, turns the function call into a closure (the argument is bound to the method)

Comment: absolutely he is calling function once , how he aspect many hello worlds printed

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. It says so in OPs question that he wants "and for each 10 seconds it must print the 'Hello, world!' string once"

Comment: I meant every 10 seconds print the string. Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: ...and don't mind the `global e_times` part, it was for other purposes.

Comment: @TrietVoNguyenMinh Try out the answer I posted. Does it do what what you want?

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate everyone's help in this question because I'm a noob at Python. Problem has now been solved!

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't make sense to me about your functions after reading your expectation about the program you want to build... I would simply use the following code:

```
from time import sleep

def _print(n, s): # n = sleep for seconds, s = string to print
    while True: # infinite loop
        print(s) # print the string
        sleep(n) # sleep for number of seconds you specify

sleep(20) # initial sleep of 20 seconds
_print("Hello, World!", 10) # run the custom print function which sleeps for n seconds and prints s string
```

Hope you have got what you want.

Comment: Post what you want to do, community will help you what must be done.

Answer (score -1):

```
from time import *
from random import * 

def _print(s):
    global e_times
    print(s)
    return 10

def doloop(call_func, s_delay):
        sleep(s_delay)
        while True:
            l_delay = call_func()
            sleep(l_delay)

doloop(lambda: _print('Hello, world!'), 20)
```

you have to use lambda function sometimes. lamda functions like variables passed to the function.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate everyone's help in this question because I'm a noob at Python. Problem has now been solved!